# Ruby on Rails Routing Alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I'm trying to add a route alias to a ruby on rails app. Here is my existing routing file:

```
scope "/blog" do    
  resources :tags, :path => :tags, :as => :tags, :only => [:index, :show] do
    match 'page/:page' => 'tags#show', :on => :member
  end
end
```

Which works great for routes like:

**/blog/tags/sandwiches**

However, I would like to add an alias (without redirecting) for a few special tags, so I can reference them like this:

**/blog/sandwiches**

I added this matching statement inside my /blog scope:

```
match 'sandwiches' => 'tags#show', :defaults => { :id => 1 }
```

But I am now getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in TagsController#show

undefined method `cache_key' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems like it's getting routed to the correct method, but a caching(?) error seems to have cropped up.

I've also put the full trace up as a gist:

https://gist.github.com/whitnelson/6598921

Comment: Can you post the line which raises the error? Maybe the stack trace too

Comment: I've added the full trace above.

Comment: What is the line 13 of your controller?

Comment: @format = 'ajax_form' #However, it also says "in `show'", but there is no show method. I assume show is being create automatically by Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Yes it is generate via the resources method in the routes.rb file. It generates the CRUD actions minus the "except" ones, or just the actions contained in the "only" option (in your case, index & show)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
class SpecialTagssConstraint
  require 'set'
  def initialize
    @ok_tags = Set.new(['sandwiches','pastries'])
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @ok_tags.include?(request.params[:id])
  end
end

 ...
    get '/:id', to: 'tags#show', constraints: SpecialTagsConstraint.new
```

I'm pretty sure you will need to use a different parameter name than :id though.

It should be whatever parameter you would normally pass with the value 'sandwiches'.

Without seeing your model, I can't guess what that is.  (tag?, name?,)